# regular expression that matches a string which comprises of only specific letters

Tags: c#, regex

I've tried several regex combinations to figure out this, but some or the condition fails,

I have an input string, that could only contain a given set of defined characters

lets say A , B or C in it.

how do I match for something like this?

ABBBCCC -- isMatch True

AAASDFDCCC  -- isMatch false

ps. I'm using C#

Comment: yes... it will Match.... Any string that has A and/or B and/or C will match

Comment: what about case sensitivity?  Will aBBBbBc match?

Comment: @David: I have string that is in AllCaps

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
 ^[ABC]+$
```

Should be enough: that is using a [Character class or Character Set](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

The [Anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) '^' and '$' would be there only to ensure the all String contains only those characters from start to end.

```
Regex.Match("ABACBA", "^[ABC]+$"); // => matches
```

Meaning: a Character Set will not guarantee the order of he characters matched.

```
Regex.Match("ABACBA", "^A+B+C+$"); // => false
```

Would guarantee the order

Comment: Thanks VonC, Works Perfect, I was using [ABC]+ which I thought would be fine, but the Anchor and $ are required.... Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks for the ordering tip, that is going to help me out.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this:

```
Match m = Regex.Match("abracadabra", "^[ABC]*$");
if (m.Success) {
   // Macth
}
```

Comment: "^[ABC]*$" will also match an empty string. To force at least one of the chars to be present, change it to "^[ABC]+$"